# Генерация xml при обращении робота

Tags: xml

Появилась задача генерации xml файла с данными при обращении к файлу определенного робота.

Прошу подсказать, по какому принципу это можно реализовать?

Comment: @Saturn, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Какого робота, что за платформа и пр.

Comment: До этого не приходилось работать с xml.

Робот будет смотреть файл через определенные промежутки времени. 
Как я это представляю. Я делаю выборку необходимых данных через php, записываю их в файл xml. А вот затем уже затруднение... как мне обновлять этот файл с момента последнего захода робота? Робот ведь, как я понимаю будет смотреть xml, а не пхп файл.

И вообще правильно ли так делать?

Comment: @Saturn, делайте алиас. То есть робот запрашивает xml, а вы выдаёте ему по запросу php, который посылает хедеры о том, что он xml-ка и генерит содержимое на ходу. А там уже Ваша задача проста, учитывая то, что Вы будете знать о том, что к Вам заходил робот и что он смотрел.

Comment: @stck, что именно значит алиас? Робот будет заходить по определенному url, в котором лежит xml файл. Расширение файла xml ведь будет. Что-то я не совсем понял.

Comment: @Saturn, это значит подмена - ответ @Palnervan именно то, что Вам нужно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого существует [htaccess](https://www.google.com.ua/search?client=opera&rls=ru&q=htaccess&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest)

```
RewriteRule ^some.xml$ xml_generate.php [L]
```

Робот идет по ссылке `some.xml` а сервер отдает то что находится в `xml_generate.php`. Таким образом работает к примеру RSS